# How can I print a Dictionary in c++ ? This is the code that im running, and I cant get to work the printDicionary method

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

This is the code that im running, and I cant get to work the printDicionary method.
Im not sure how to use the vector i created and i want to know how could I print all of the elements in this way:

[0]:

[1]: (1501, “adiós”), (301, “nuevo”)

[2]:

[3]: (23, “perro”)

…

[5]: (15, “hola”)

…

[9]: (9, “gato”)

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class K, class V>
class KeyPair{
    public:
    K key;
    V value;

    KeyPair(){
        key=NULL;
        value=NULL;
    }

    KeyPair(K key, V val){
        this->key=key;
        this->value=val;
    }
};

template <class K, class V>
class Dictionary{
    public:
    vector<KeyPair<K,V> > *dict;
    int positions;

    Dictionary(){
        positions=10;
        dict=new vector<KeyPair<K,V> >[positions];
    }

    Dictionary(int pos){
        positions=pos;
        dict=new vector<KeyPair<K,V> >[positions];
    }

    void insert(K key, V value){
        KeyPair<K,V> kp(key, value);
        int hash=key%positions;
        for(int i=0; i<dict[hash].size(); i++){
            if(dict[hash][i].key==key){
                cout<<"llave ya existente"<<endl;
                return;
            }
        }
        dict[hash].push_back(kp);
        //dict//arreglo de vectores keypair
        //dict[hash]//vector de keypair

    }

    V checkAtKey(K key){
        int hash=key%positions;
        for(int i=0; i<dict[hash].size(); i++){
            if(dict[hash][i].key==key){
                return dict[hash][i].value;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    void printDictionary(){
```

> This is where i created the method

```
        for(int i=0; i<dict[i].size(); i++){

        cout << dict.key <<endl;
```

> Im not sure if this is the way i should call the dict

```
        cout << dict.value <<endl;
        return;


            }

        }




};

int main(){
    Dictionary<int, string> a;
    a.insert(5, "perro");
    a.insert(4, "gato");
  Dictionary<int, string> b;
  b.insert(15, "lombriz");

  b.printDictionary();
}
```

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this kind of a thing. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using brief, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Assigning `NULL` only makes sense for pointers (it may or may not compile for integers depending on the compiler). If you want to initialize `key` and `value` with sensible default values, it's better to simply do `K key; V value;`. Also, if you know what a `vector` is, why use `new[]` to allocate `dict`? Wouldn't it be easier to use `vector<vector<KeyPair<K,V>>> dict;`?

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of mistakes in your code, man.

the "kp" member of Dictionary is a pointer (it has that "*" star), so you must use "->" to access its members, such as ".at(i)", which is the same as [i], or ".push_back(i)" to add an element at the end of the vector.

i have put your original code in comments and replaced it with the right code so you can see what changes i made. ask me if you wanna know more about what i changed, bro. good luck!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class K, class V> class KeyPair
{
public:

    K key;
    V value;

    KeyPair()
    {
        key = NULL;
        value = NULL;
    }

    KeyPair(K key, V val)
    {
        this->key = key;
        this->value = val;
    }

 };

template<class K, class V> class Dictionary
{
public:

    vector<KeyPair<K,V>> * dict;
    int positions;

    Dictionary()
    {
        positions = 10;
        dict = new vector<KeyPair<K, V>>[positions];
    }

    Dictionary(int pos)
    {
        positions = pos;
        dict = new vector<KeyPair<K, V>>[positions];
    }

    void insert(K key, V value)
    {
        KeyPair<K, V> kp(key, value);

        //int hash = key % positions;

        //for (int i = 0; i < dict[hash].size(); i++)
        for (int i = 0; i < dict->size(); i++)
        {
            //if (dict[hash][i].key == key)
            if (dict->at(i).key == key)
            {
                cout << "llave ya existente" << endl;
                return;
            }
        }

        //dict[hash].push_back(kp);
        dict->push_back(kp);
    }

    V checkAtKey(K key)
    {
        //int hash = key % positions;

        //for (int i = 0; i < dict[hash].size(); i++)   
        for (int i = 0; i < dict->size(); i++)
        {
            //if (dict[hash][i].key == key)
            if (dict->at(i).key == key)
            {
                //return dict[hash][i].value;
                return dict->at(i).value;
            }
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    void printDictionary()
    {
        //for (int i = 0; i < dict[i].size(); i++){
        for (int i = 0; i < dict->size(); i++)
        {
            // cout << dict.value << endl;
            KeyPair<K, V> curr_key = dict->at(i);
            printf("%d - %s\n", curr_key.key, curr_key.value.c_str());
            // or you can do this
            // std::cout << curr_key.key << " - " << curr_key.value.c_str();
        }
    }
 };

int main()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> a;
    a.insert(5, "perro");
    a.insert(4, "gato");
    Dictionary<int, string> b;
    b.insert(15, "lombriz");

    b.printDictionary();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the help, i dont really understan what you did in the printDictionary() part, like i've never herd of currkey and all that. still the code didnt work on terminal so it didnt print all the elemnts of the vector.

Comment: it's printing all of the elements. you are printing "b", and "b" only has 1 element: "15 - lombriz". you can do "a.printDictionary()" to get the others.

Comment: as for printDictionary(): the "dict" vector is a vector of KeyPair structure, correct? in order to read the elements in the structure, i am saving it in another KeyPair structure instance, then reading from there

Comment: doing "dict->at(i).key" and "dict->at(i).value.c_str()" would achieve the same thing